# Programming: Give the count of all such numbers which have 3 in their decimal representation

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

Given a number n, write a function that returns count of numbers from 1 to n that don’t contain digit 3 in their decimal representation

What can be the most optimal way of solving this problem.

the approach i am using in naive i.e nlogn (easy to guess the approach by seeing complexity :)   )

Comment: @Marcin thot of seeing the pattern how 3 occurs at every place(place as in at units place , tens place etc) , At units place 3 occurs after every 10 iterations , similarly at tens place ... thot of doing something like this , but could not get to a solution

Comment: In general, the best way to address these sorts of problems is not to ask SO, but to read literature in the appropriate branch of mathematics. This is combinatorics.

Comment: What is your n log n algorithm?

Comment: @templatetypedef kinda brute force , iterate from 1 to n checking all digits , as no of digits are of the order logn so its nlogn

Comment: the title says number with 3 in decimal representation.  the first sentence says "that don't contain digit 3".  which do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following algorithm computes the number of integers from 0 to (n-1) without "3" in their decimal representation quite efficiently. (I have modified the interval from 1 .. n to 0 .. n-1 only to simplify the following calculations slightly.)

*(I am not an expert in complexity calculations, but I think the complexity of this algorithm is `O(log n)`, because it does a fixed number of steps for each digit of `n`.)*

The first observation is that the number of integers with at most d digits (i.e. the numbers in the interval 0 .. 10<sup>d</sup>-1) not having the digit 3 in their decimal representation is exactly 9<sup>d</sup>, because for each digit you have 9 possible choices 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Now let me demonstrate the algorithm with a 5 digit number n = a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>0</sub>.

We compute separately the number of integers with no "3" in their decimal representation for the intervals

- I<sub>0</sub>: a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>1</sub> 0 <= i < a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>0</sub>
- I<sub>1</sub>: a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub> 0 0 <= i < a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>1</sub> 0
- I<sub>2</sub>: a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub> 0 0 0 <= i < a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub>a<sub>2</sub> 0 0
- I<sub>3</sub>: a<sub>4</sub> 0 0 0 0 <= i < a<sub>4</sub>a<sub>3</sub> 0 0 0
- I<sub>4</sub>: 0 0 0 0 0 <= i < a<sub>4</sub> 0 0 0 0

The number of integers in the interval I<sub>j</sub> that do not have a "3" in the decimal representation is

- 0, if one of the higher valued digits a<sub>j+1</sub>, a<sub>j+2</sub>, ... is equal to 3,
  otherwise:
- a<sub>j</sub> * 9<sup>j</sup>, if 0 <= a<sub>j</sub> <= 3, (a<sub>j</sub> choices for the
  j<sup>th</sup> digit, 9 choices for all lower valued digits),
- (a<sub>j</sub> - 1) * 9<sup>j</sup>, if aj > 3 (because 3 is not a valid choice for the j<sup>th</sup> digit) .

So we have the following function:

```
/*
 * Compute number of integers x with 0 <= x < n that do not
 * have a 3 in their decimal representation.
 */
int f(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    int a;      // The current digit a_j
    int p = 1;  // The current value of 9^j

    while (n > 0) {
        a = n % 10;
        if (a == 3) {
            count = 0;
        }
        if (a <= 3) {
            count += a * p;
        } else {
            count += (a-1) * p;
        }
        n /= 10;
        p *= 9;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: "The first observation is that the number of integers with at most d digits (i.e. the numbers in the interval 0 .. 10^(d-1)) is exactly 9^d, because for each digit you have 9 possible choices 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9." - as it stands, this is wrong. 0-9 is 10 digits, the number of such integers is `10^d`, not `9^d`. Haven't had time to look over the rest, but this part is wrong.

Comment: @IVlad: The entire question is about numbers "not having the digit 3 in their decimal representation" and that is what I meant here. I will fix that in the answer immediately. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Yeah, it looks better now. Didn't see there's no 3 there and that was a bit confusing.